# Git merge using KDiff3 and Meld?

Tags: git, meld, kdiff3

I have configured KDiff3 as my default merge tool in the Git configuration so that when there is a merge conflict and on using the command

```
git mergetool
```

KDiff3 opens as my merge editor.

I would like to try Git merge through meld from the command line without modifying my Git configuration from KDiff3.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try:

```
git mergetool --tool=meld <files>
```